# How to change Table 1: to Table 1 :

Tags: captions

May I ask your assistance for the following

Now I have `Table 1:`

and I would like to change to `Table 1 :`  (there is a space between "1" and the semicolon.

if it's helpful, the following are the package I'm using

`\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=colon}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You're using the `caption` package -- it has some good documentation how to change this kind of things, e.g. `\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{morespace}{~:}` is the command you need, most likely, then use `labelsep=morespace`, but a precise solution requires the knowledge on the documentclass, which is not given, since there is only one fragment of code given here

Comment: With `babel-french`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: I beg your pardon, but a thin (or medium sized) unbreakable space before a colon or a semi-colon is the norm in French.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: I recommend the *Guide Typographique de l'Imprimerie Nationale* ;o)

Comment: @Bernard BTW, I should have noticed that Altermundus' manuals use that kind of punctuation!

Comment: It seems it's Alain Matthes' site, who's French – that's an excellent reason…

Answer (score 3):

In your preamble, the following should do the trick:

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{frenchcolon}{\,: }
\captionsetup{labelsep=frenchcolon}
```

*Added* : Egreg's solution for a real french spacing.

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{frenchcolon}{\unskip\nobreak\hspace{.5\fontdimen2\font}: }
```

Comment: My education also aimed at politeness, milady…

Comment: Not at all! I just meant it's natural to be polite.

Comment: I'm under the impression it should be `~:` rather than `\,:`; as far as I know, the spaces around the colon should be normal interword spaces and, particularly, equal on either side.

Comment: @egreg: as far as I remember, purists use an unbreakable medsized space. It should correspond more or less to `\:` in math mode) but I don't know whether it is defined by LaTeX (as *non-breaking* space.

Comment: That would be `\unskip\nobreak\hspace{.5\fontdimen2\font}:` (adjusting the fraction to suit). I checked on a copy of the “Récherche” published by Gallimard and, indeed, the spaces at either side can be different; on the left it is fixed. I'd like better a punch in my eye, *ça va sans dire*. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks a lot! I've added it. I suppose `frenchb` has something like that in its internals (or may be late Bernard Gaulle's `french.sty`?).